# Possible to copy char *a[] and char *b[]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory

Say I have made 2 char *arrays[]:

```
char *a[some number] = {0};
char *b[some number] = {0};

//do some operations and set elements for char *a[]
```

How would I copy the elements of char *a[] to char *b[] without setting b[index] = a[index]. Since this would end up having b[index] point to a[index] (and I would like to then change a[index], without changing or affecting b[index]).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Copy what are pointed at by the elements of `a` and assign pointers to the copies to the elements of `b`. If what are pointed are strings (sequences of characters terminated by null-characters), [`strdup()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) should be useful (if it is available in your environment). Otherwise, you have to determine the size to copy by some means. Also be careful not to dereference `NULL` for copying.

Comment: I think the concept you're asking about is a "deep copy". Copying the contents of `a` to `b` is a shallow copy. To perform a deep copy, you need to make a copy of every object that `a` points to, and then put the pointer-to-the-copy into `b`. That way, nothing that you do with `a` will affect anything related to `b`.

Comment: `b[index] = a[index]` results in both `b[index]` and `a[index]` pointing to some object elsewhere in memory .  They do not point to each other

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks! that was exactly what I was looking for! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the pointers in both arrays reference valid char arrays.

```
memcpy(b[x], a[x], size_of_of_the_object_referenced_by_b[x]);
```

Comment: Your source and destination looks swapped.